# Ionic3 ng2-charts: chart not loading

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, ng2-charts

I'm trying to use ng2-charts in my Ionic 3 project to display a cumulative graph of data that I'm getting from Cloud Firestore, but the data received isn't plotted on the graph.

cumulative.html:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div>
    <div style="display: block">
      <canvas baseChart height="350"
              [datasets]="barChartData"
              [labels]="barChartLabels"
              [options]="barChartOptions"
              [legend]="barChartLegend"
              [chartType]="barChartType"
              (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
              (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div> 
</ion-content>
```

cumulative.ts:

```
export class CumulativePage {

  public barChartOptions:any  = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    scaleShowValues: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }; 

  public barChartLabels:string[] = [];
  public barChartType:string = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

  public barChartData:any[] = [
    {data: [], label: 'time'}
  ];

  public chartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public classId: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public afs: AngularFirestore) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.classId = this.navParams.get('className');
    console.log(this.classId);

    let queryCol = this.afs.collection('sessions', ref => ref.where('name', '==', this.classId));
    let query = queryCol.snapshotChanges();
    query.subscribe((snap) => {
      snap.forEach(q => {
        console.log(q.payload.doc.id);
        let sessionId = q.payload.doc.id;
        this.afs.collection('sessions').doc(sessionId).collection('helpList').ref.get()
          .then(snap => {
            snap.forEach(doc => {
              let data = doc.data() as Help;
              let exists = false;
              this.barChartLabels.forEach(user => {
                if (user == doc.data().userId){
                  let index = this.barChartLabels.indexOf(user);
                  this.barChartData[0].data[index] += doc.data().time;
                  exists = true;
                }
                else{
                  console.log(user, doc.data().userId);
                }
              })
              if (exists == false){
                this.barChartLabels.push(doc.data().userId);
                this.barChartData[0].data.push(doc.data().time);
                console.log(this.barChartLabels);
                console.log(this.barChartData);
              }    
            })

          })
      })
    })
    console.log(this.barChartLabels);
    console.log(this.barChartData);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the user ID and time from various documents in Firestore and add up the times to get a total time for each user. (this.barChartLabels stores the user IDs and this.barChartData stores the total time).

When I console.log this.barChartLabels and this.barChartData, the correct data appears in the console, but I just get a set of empty axes appearing on the page.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me figure out why the graph isn't plotting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He, What happens is that ng2-charts uses behind ChartJS and for reasons that do not explain you the to-way databinding does not work for ng2-charts, then your graph is drawn before the data is and therefore when the data is already the graph is not rendered again.

For this I propose a trick that works for me. I declare a variable in the attributes of type boolean in false, and with a conficional * ngIF of angular I say to the view that it is not drawn until the variable is not true. Then that variable I set to true only when I finished loading the data completely.

For exmaple, my view:

```
<div *ngIf="redraw == true" style="display: block;">
          <canvas baseChart width="300" height="400"
                      [datasets]="lineChartData1"
                      [labels]="lineChartLabels1"
                      [options]="lineChartOptions1"
                      [colors]="lineChartColors1"
                      [legend]="lineChartLegend1"
                      [chartType]="lineChartType1"
                      (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                      (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
          </div>
```

The redraw variable is only set to true when you have already obtained the data and assigned it to lineChartData1.